# How to make conditions when inserting empty data in masked text box in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm try to make 3 conditions when inserting date using masked text box. The data that I'm trying to insert into the database is passport date, it is not a required data to be inserted as not all user have passport. First condition is when there are user leave the passport date empty, the null data will be save into the database. Seconds condition is when user insert date that are not true such as "29/02/2019", a msgbox will be shown. Lastly, when user insert proper date, data will be save into database.

I've already use "textbox.Text.Trim().Length = 0" syntax but the condition does not work.

```vb
Private Sub insert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles insert.Click

    'insert syntax
    Dim insert_command As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO employee(StaffID, StaffName, ExpiredDate1) _
    VALUES (@StaffID, @StaffName, @ExpiredDate1)", connection)

    'insert staffid
    If staffid.Text.Trim().Length > 0 Then
        insert_command.Parameters.Add("@StaffID", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = staffid.Text
    End If

    'insert staffname
    If staffname.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
        insert_command.Parameters.Add("@StaffName", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = DBNull.Value
    Else
        insert_command.Parameters.Add("@StaffName", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = staffname.Text
    End If

    'insert passport date
    Dim dob As Date   

    If edate1.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
        insert_command.Parameters.Add("@ExpiredDate1", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = DBNull.Value
    ElseIf Date.TryParse(edate1.Text, dob) Then
        insert_command.Parameters.Add("@ExpiredDate1", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = edate1.Text
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid passport date", "Invalid Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, _
        MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If
End Sub
```

The error that I got is when user does leave the date masked text box null, it does not insert the null data but read the last condition. I want user able to insert null data into the database without showing the last condition msgbox.

Comment: Then obviously the length of the text is not 0.  Did you bother to actually look at the `Text` to see what it is under those circumstances?  That's why VS has a debugger.  You don;t have to guess.  You can place a breakpoint on that line and see what the value is while the code is executing.  I suggest that you also read the documentation for the `MaskedTextBox` class to see how it works, e.g. the `MaskFull` property.

Comment: Also, why oh why are you storing dates as text in the database?  Would you store numbers as text?  I certainly hope not.  If you wouldn't do that, why would you store dates as text?  Apart from anything else, how can you sort data chronologically that isn't chronological data?

Comment: Why are you using a masked text box? As jmcilhinney stated, you need to read its documentary. I think a textbox is better for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio I can place a breakpoint before this line

```
If edate1.Text.Trim().Length = 0 Then
```

Then when I execute the code in Debug mode and hit the button on the form, I can hover my mouse over the `.Text` function to see what the textfield contains.

Because I have not entered anything yet it shows me `"  /  /"`. Apparently even an empty value still has the mask, so `.Length = 0` will not work.

The easiest way would be to check if the field still has that default value, but that might cause a problem if the mask were ever to change.

When I hover my mouse over the `edate1` variable (while still paused on the breakpoint) I can select a dropdown that shows me all properties and methods of that variable. I notice it has a 'MaskFull' and 'MaskCompleted' which might be of use (a full list can also be seen in the [.Net Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox)).

Let's test it out:

```
If Not edate1.MaskFull Then
    Debug.Print("Not full")
ElseIf Date.TryParse(edate1.Text, dob) Then
    Debug.Print("Date!")
Else
    Debug.Print("Not full, no date")
End If
```

Output

- `"  /  /"` 'Not full'.
- `"01/01/197"` 'Not full'.
- `"01/01/1970"` 'Date!'.
- `"12/34/1970"` 'Not full, no date'.